# Echo Title and Quantity when a checkbox is checked?

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

I have a form that lets the user select an item and input its quantity. My question is how do i echo it in the next page using session? For example if a user selects OPTION-1 with a quantity of 4, the next page would echo **Selected:Option1 (4)**. Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
          <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="combos[]" class="drink" value="Title1" data-price="560" />
              <input min="0" max="20" type="number" class="quantity" name="comboscount[]" value="true" placeholder="0"/><p>Quantity</p>
          </label>

         <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="combos[]" class="drink" value="Title2" data-price="322" />
          <input min="0" max="20" type="number" class="quantity" name="comboscount[]" value="true" placeholder="0"/><p>Quantity</p>
        </label>

        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="combos[]" class="drink" value="Title3" data-price="231" />
          <input min="0" max="20" type="number" class="quantity" name="comboscount[]" value="true" placeholder="0"/><p>Quantity</p>
        </label>
```

And here's how I process it in page 2:

```
$_SESSION['combos'] = $_POST['combos'];
$_SESSION['comboscount'] = $_POST['comboscount'];

   if(empty($_SESSION['combos'])) 
  {
   echo "Combos: <br />"."Nothing was selected."."<br /><br />";
  } 
  else
  {
   echo ("Combos: <br />");
   foreach ($_SESSION['combos'] as $key => $val) {
   echo $val." (".$_SESSION['comboscount'][$key].")<br />";
}
   echo ("<br />");
  }
```

I got the array of title to list, but as for the quantity is empty. Did I miss something in the processing of the array?

Once again thanks.

Comment: Why do you use `value="true"` for a `type="number"` input?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the keys for `$_SESSION['combos']` as the keys for `$_SESSION['comboscount']`, because only the checked checkboxes are submitted to the server. They'll get sequential indexes starting from `0`, but the unchecked boxes won't be in that sequence. On the other hand, all the text boxes will be submitted. So the indexes of the two arrays will not correspond to matching elements in the form.

What you can do is put explicit indexes into all the names, to keep them in sync.

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="combos[0]" class="drink" value="Title1" data-price="560" />
    <input min="0" max="20" type="number" class="quantity" name="comboscount[0]" value="true" placeholder="0"/><p>Quantity</p>
</label>

<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="combos[1]" class="drink" value="Title2" data-price="322" />
    <input min="0" max="20" type="number" class="quantity" name="comboscount[1]" value="true" placeholder="0"/><p>Quantity</p>
</label>

<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="combos[2]" class="drink" value="Title3" data-price="231" />
    <input min="0" max="20" type="number" class="quantity" name="comboscount[2]" value="true" placeholder="0"/><p>Quantity</p>
</label>
```

The indexes in the text boxes are redundant, but it's helpful to see the explicit correlations.

The code that creates the form should be able to fill in the indexes automatically:

```
foreach ($items as $index => $item) { ?>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="combos[<?php echo $index; ?>]" class="drink" value="<?php echo $item['name']; ?>" data-price="<?php echo $item['price']; ?>" />
        <input min="0" max="20" type="number" class="quantity" name="comboscount[<?php echo $index; ?>]" value="true" placeholder="0"/><p>Quantity</p>
    </label>
<?php ;
```

Comment: Thank @barmar. It could be a solution but the problem is I've also looped the label in the form so that the form would display checkboxes in that certain category. So my checkbox looks like this:  <input type="checkbox" name="combos[]" class="drink" value=get the_title" data-price="get the_content" /> so mu db automatically populates that. How can i apply thre index then?

Comment: Don't try to put code in comments. If there's more details in the problem, edit the question.

Comment: Im sorry. Will edit it later as i am on mobile. Thanks

Comment: I've added to my answer showing how to populate the name attributes.